# Jquery mobile .on("pagebeforecreate") How can I find the id of the page being loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a function that upons discovering that the page is being loaded, it will load Json from a server and then alter html in the page being loaded before it is loaded with the Json data.

So far, I have come up with this solution, however, I can't find a way to get the name of the page being loaded to determine what type of data and html data injections should be used (page handler).

Would anyone happen to know a function or method I can use to determine the page name/id upon the "pagebeforecreate" event? Or even better, a better way to perform the html injection upon page load?

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function(event) {

  var loadingPage = //NEED FUNCTION FOR PAGE BEING LOADED
    var print = "";

  if (at == "createAccountPage") {
    $.getJSON('http://71.162.197.6/iGotChu/php/listUsers.php', function(jsonData) {
      alert("hello");

    });

    document.getElementById("usersList").innerHTML = print;

  }
});
```

Comment: what is it that identifies the page as unique? the name of the page, as in the title, or...?

Comment: In j query mobile each page has an id attribute which can be loaded by for example an href attribute. I am using that Id to identify the pages

Comment: <div data-role="page" id="loginPage">.   For example my login page is identified by the id login

Comment: Are you looking for jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "pagebeforecreate", function( event ) { ... } ) ??? may be you need to change document. to this code.

Comment: So if I select all of the <a> with that selector instead of the documents and then what should I do next to extract the  specific instance of that a tag

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The solution is quite simple and isn't clearly place on any Api or at least I couldn't find it.

Inside of the event object that is the callback function for the "pagebeforecreate" function, there is a field that indicates the id of the page being loaded.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate",function(event){
```

For example in this clip, the call back function passes the event object. You can use the console.log(event) function to display the elements of the object. If I can post a picture you can see the elements of the object. In there, there is an id field with the page being loaded. With that, you can use it as a page handler to run specific injections for your next page before it is created.

This is the final code.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate",function(event){
var nextPage = event.target.id;
  var print = "";
            if (nextPage=="createAccountPage"){
                $.ajax({
                  url: '~your URL',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  async: false,
                  success: function(data) {
                    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
                        print = print + "<li><a href='index.html'><img src='images/album-bb.jpg' /><h3>Broken Bells</h3><p>Broken Bells</p></a></li>";
                        } 
                        document.getElementById("usersList").innerHTML = print;
                        print = "";
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

**Even more, If you attempt to make a JSON call, the call must MUST be synchronous as set in the async field. This is because the call must block and load the data before the page is created. If done otherwise, the page will load before the javascript can get to it and apply the styling.